# Why am I not getting an error (or at least warning) when I pass a number to a function that is expecting an enum?

Tags: c

I'm using gcc for an ARM Cortex M4 and doing the following:

```
uint32_t SetGyroInterruptBits(enum Gyr_Int_Set_Bits BitMap)
{
//    Code Here
return RelevantValue;

}
```

I created the enums as follows:

```
enum Gyr_Int_Set_Bits 
{
    HR_FILT = 0x80,
    AM_FILT = 0x40,
    HR_Z_AXIS = 0x20,
    HR_Y_AXIS = 0x10,
    HR_X_AXIS = 0x08,
    AM_Z_AXIS = 0x04,
    AM_Y_AXIS = 0x02,
    AM_X_AXIS = 0x01,
};
```

When I call this function as follows:

```
SetGyroInterruptBits(34);
```

I expected to get at least a warning telling me I should be passing an enum. However, it compiles completely happily. I thought this was an advantage of enums over just using a #define. Is it a warning you have to specifically ask the compiler to check for or do I just misunderstand? Is using a #define just as good in this instance?

Comment: What compiler you are using, and at which warning level?

Comment: As I said, I'm using the gcc for the Cortex M4. As tp the warning level I have no idea. I will investigate how to dig out that info.

Comment: Sorry for the compiler question, I didn't see it. My gcc issues: "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'MyEnum' **[-fpermissive]**"

Comment: @user5329483, are you using a C compiler or a C++ compiler... because C enums are integer compatible... but C++ I think not.

Comment: @LuisColorado; Yeap, it was C++. I used to test my C code in a cpp file. The C++ compiler will complain about questionable C constructs more pedantic.

Comment: @user5329483 ...but this question is tagged C only...

Answer (score 2):

In C an enumeration is just a symbolic compile-time constant of type `int`. You can assign *any* `int` value to an enumeration, even if it's not a valid value for the enumeration.

Passing the integer value `34` is the same as passing `HR_Z_AXIS | AM_Y_AXIS`.

Comment: So, using enum fin this instance holds no advantage over #defines?

Comment: @DiBosco No not really, for bits it's really not that useful. But for things like states or similar, that are used in `switch` cases, it might be useful as then some compilers will warn you if you do not have a `case` for each enumeration.

Comment: 34 is still not a member of the enumeration, so a pedantic compiler should warn.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK, thank  you. I must confess I always just use #defines, they just seem more intuitive to me.

Comment: @user5329483 This was my thinking. I might try getting the compiler to be more pedantic.

Comment: @DiBosco You can enable more warnings with GCC using the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` arguments. I recommend you always use them actually.

Comment: @user5329483 Which makes bit values and masks using enumerations even more worthless.

Comment: Feel free to write one of those hardly discussed typecasts `(MyEnumeration)(HR_Z_AXIS | AM_Y_AXIS)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: As usual: The sum of the sh*t is constant: Do you want to use #define for binary flags or enums?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Just by the way: Not all enums are sizeof(int). Some compiler implementations allowing small-enums, just one byte, if appropriate.